# writing sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How would you write a query to select the rooms which are booked between
2012-05-1 and 2012-11-01 from a booking database?

Comment: What are your ideas? Show me your attempt, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following

```
SELECT * from room
WHERE (roomNo, hotelNo) not in
( select roomNo, hotelNo
  from booking
  where datefrom between '2012-05-01' and '2012-11-01'
  or dateto between '2012-05-01' and '2012-11-01'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select r.* from rooms r 
left outer join bookings b on b.roomno = r.roomno
where b.dateto not between '2012-05-01' and '2012-11-01'
and b.datefrom not between '2012-05-01' and '2012-11-01'
or b.roomno is null
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c4f8/1)

Comment: And what happens if the booking period is in the middle of the start of the end date ? You don't get who have a room booked in the middle of start or end date ...

Comment: @juergend May not work with rooms that have no bookings so far.

Comment: @AmitBhargava: Thanks for the hint. I forgot to put the `left outer join` in it. It has been in the SQLFiddle example though.

Answer (score 2):

This should include all rooms that aren't booked between the two given dates :

```
SELECT * FROM Room r
JOIN Booking b ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo AND r.roomNo = b.roomNo
WHERE NOT ('2012-05-01' BETWEEN (b.dateFrom AND b.dateTo)
OR '2012-11-01' BETWEEN (b.dateFrom AND b.dateTo))
```